# sslscan: How to interpret the output with respect to to curves used for key exchange?

Tags: ssl, cipher

`sslscan` produces the following output (truncated for the purposes of this question):

```
  Supported Server Cipher(s):
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.3  256 bits  TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384        Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Preferred TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM8       Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM        Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384         DHE 3072 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384     Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA384 Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ADH-AES256-SHA256             DHE 3072 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ADH-CAMELLIA256-SHA256        DHE 3072 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256 Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA        Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  AECDH-AES256-SHA              Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ADH-AES256-SHA                DHE 3072 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ADH-CAMELLIA256-SHA           DHE 3072 bits

  Server Key Exchange Group(s):
TLSv1.3  128 bits  secp256r1 (NIST P-256)
TLSv1.3  192 bits  secp384r1 (NIST P-384)
TLSv1.3  260 bits  secp521r1 (NIST P-521)
TLSv1.3  128 bits  x25519
TLSv1.3  224 bits  x448
TLSv1.3  112 bits  ffdhe2048
TLSv1.3  128 bits  ffdhe3072
TLSv1.2  192 bits  secp384r1 (NIST P-384)

  SSL Certificate:
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
ECC Curve Name:      secp384r1
ECC Key Strength:    192
```

In the list of supported ciphers at the top, all ciphers which use ECDH are reported with the curve 25519. In the list of key exchange groups at the bottom, the curve NIST P-384 is the only curve which is listed for TLS 1.2.

How is this output supposed to be interpreted?

Is the curve 25519 only reported as an example in the the list of ciphers above and does the server supported any of the curves at the bottom with any of the cipher suites?

Theoretically, TLS1.2 also supports any of the reported curves for DH key exchange. Why is only NIST P-384 explicitly listed for TLS 1.2 and all other curves only in combination with TLS 1.3. This kind of output confuses me.

Comment: Could it be your server configuration? For eg, nginx has a separate way of configuring TLS1.3(ssl_conf_command Ciphersuites) and TLS1.2(ssl_ciphers).

Do you get the same output when you try sslscan on www.yahoo.com? I get:
```
TLSv1.3  128 bits  secp256r1 (NIST P-256)
TLSv1.3  192 bits  secp384r1 (NIST P-384)
TLSv1.3  260 bits  secp521r1 (NIST P-521)
TLSv1.3  128 bits  x25519
TLSv1.3  224 bits  x448
TLSv1.2  128 bits  secp256r1 (NIST P-256)
TLSv1.2  192 bits  secp384r1 (NIST P-384)
TLSv1.2  260 bits  secp521r1 (NIST P-521)
TLSv1.2  128 bits  x25519
TLSv1.2  224 bits  x448
```